# How do I deserialize circular references (serialized by Newtonsoft.Json) with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, circular-reference

I have to deserialize JSON with circular references. 
The first occurrence of an object has:

```
"$id":"1"
```

The references look like:

```
{"$ref":"1"}
```

With @JsonIdentityInfo I can make the $id readable but Jackson won't read the references.
If I manually delete the "$ref" stuff the deserialization works and only have the reference key itself in the JSON string.

How can I make Jackson handle references in the "$ref" style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my own Deserializer but it seems to be much to complicated for this pretty simple problem.

The class I want to deserialize gets:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="$id")
```

I take the whole JSON string and replace the ref stuff by regexp.

```
String regex = "\\{\\\"\\$ref\\\":\\\"(\\d{1,})*\\\"\\}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jsonString);
String resultString="";
if (matcher.find())
{
    resultString = matcher.replaceAll("$1");
}
```

Replacing the string takes almost no time.